# Write a JUnit functional test for a prebuilt apk

Tags: android, dependencies, apk

Still being relatively green to things, I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to write JUnit functional tests against a prebuilt app sans source. I've found a means of re-signing the app but I'd like to know how to include it in an Eclipse project as a dependency of my tests?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is indeed possible using Java reflections.

Besides this, it can be necessary to resign the app you want to test. Download it from your device (e.g., using the app AppMonster), resign it using the resign.jar (http://www.troido.de/re-sign.jar) and install it again using adb.

Afterwards, everything should work fine.

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class YourTestSuite extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

    /** Package ID of the app under test. */
    private static final String TARGET_PACKAGE_ID = "com.something";

    /** ID of the app under test's main activity. */
    private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "com.something.HomeActivity";

    /** Launcher activity class. */
    private static Class<?> launcherActivityClass;

    /** Static code to find the activity class. */
    static {
        try {
            launcherActivityClass = Class
                .forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public YourTestSuite() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        super(TARGET_PACKAGE_ID, launcherActivityClass);
    }

    /* Your test code comes here. */
}
```

Comment: looks good but how do I include the apk in an Eclipse project as a dependency of my tests? Do I rename it from app to zip and list it as a jar dependency?

Comment: You do not need any dependency in Eclipse. Just install the apk on your test device, otherwhise your test case will fail to load the activity under test during runtime. You can use the command 'adb install <filename>' to install the apk on your test device.